# momentjs toISOString without the "z"

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to create ISO-8601 date. With momentjs I'm using

moment(my_date).toISOString() to create an ISO date, the result is similar to this:

```
2015-03-17T15:12:38.076Z
```

I need to send this date to an API which expects the date a little different (although it's documentation says they're using ISO-8601):

```
2015-03-17T15:12:38.076-4:00
```

Is there a way to get the expected formatting using momentjs or something else?.

**Edit:** I found a solution:

```
moment.tz(my_date, "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use momentjs timezone: 
http://momentjs.com/timezone/

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```

The `z` inidcates an UTC timestamp, the API is expecting the difference to UTC and therefor the `-4:00`. If you do want conversions between timezones momentjs timezone is my suggested way to go.

But doesn't `moment().format();` returns the time as `2014-09-08T08:02:17-05:00` ?

Comment: I tried both, moment alone and moment timezone, but I noted a slight difference:  the string requested "2015-03-17T15:12:38.076-4:00" has seconds dot milliseconds, while the one returned by moment.format() is "2014-09-08T08:02:17-05:00" without the milliseconds. None of them returns what the API expects.

Comment: I found a solution, please look at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Btw, I'll accept this because it helped me to find the solution.